# AWS Amplify "Error getting tasks: Network Error"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I'm working on the AWS Workshop Studio, Getting Started with Serverless, serverless project.
Services used on this project: Lambda, Amazon API Gateway, AWS Amplify, Amazon DynamoDB, Amazon Rekognition, AWS Cloud9.
https://catalog.us-east-1.prod.workshops.aws/workshops/841ce16b-9d86-48ac-a3f6-6a1b29f95d2b/en-US

I was able to deploy the app and the landing page is ok
[App landing page pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ePES.png)

However, once I log in to interact with the app I get this "Error getting tasks: Network Error"
[Error Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R28Ac.png)

Anyone else run into this or any suggestions?